# Codemaid-Like Tool for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, code-formatting

I used to do a lot of work in C# but recently I got into a new role as a VB.NET developer. When I was doing C# I got to really like CodeMaid as an auto-formatting tool. Is there a tool like it for VB.NET (since CodeMaid doesn't support VB.NET)? I haven't been able to find anything in my searches (that was free anyways...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard your plea.. how about we add support for VB to CodeMaid? :)

VB support is now available in beta testing here: https://bitbucket.org/s_cadwallader/codemaid/downloads/CodeMaid_v0.5.7.4_BETA.vsix

Give it a spin and if you see issues or have suggestions shoot a message to codemaid on gmail.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).  It supports almost any language you can use in visual studio.  It may not be free, but you should give the trial a shot.

For quick 'auto-formatting' of text you can select all text in your file and use this shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

to auto-format based on your Visual Studio formatting guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET forces most of the formatting you would have to do in C#, i.e. the code gets formatted automatically. For everything else there is little development effort. You do not need any tools for that.

*Source: professional VB.NET developer for 4+ years.*